# Pyinstaller executable cannot find QtWebEngineProcess.exe

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a python program using Pyinstaller that will run PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets. Unfortunately there seems to be an issue with the relative path to QtWebEngineProcess.exe within the pyinstaller build.

I installed pyqt5 to be used with Python 2.7 following this method:
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-December/038450.html

When I compile this the executable runs fine on my machine but if I move the executable to a computer that does not have Qt installed then it gives me the error 'Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe'

Within the dist folder of the pyinstaller build there is a 'PyQt5/Qt/bin' directory that contains QtWebEngineProcess.exe. However I'm not entirely sure why it's not linking to this and still linking to the one in C:\Qt.

I'm certain it's still using the QtWebEngineProcess.exe installed at C:\Qt because if I change that directory name, the built program will fail on the machine I built it on.

At this point I'm trying to edit the paths within the qt.conf file contained in the bin file within the pyinstaller dist directory but I'm not entirely certain that's the answer to this. Ultimately I want a single file executable and by that point I can't edit the contents of the executable.

Thanks!
-Mark

Comment: I had a similar problem, but since you are running windows and not linux, I'm unsure your solution will be the same.  Try running orange as `orange-canvas --qt "--single-process"`  If that works, it might be worth trying to installl a different version of PyQT  ex: `pip install PyQt5==5.9.2`